# Removing text from One Page Check out

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using `Authorize.net` and `One page Check out`. Magento 1.7.2
  On the payment page it says`Credit Card (authorize.net)` and I want to remove the `(authorize.net)` portion of that area. Where can I access that?

Comment: check the admin->configuration->payment methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigate to `admin->system->configuration->payment methods` open the `authorize.net` tab here you a input box named as `Title` here you can edit the title.

[image]